# How can I export C++ pointer to lua?

Tags: c++, lua

In C++, I have Two Class

```
class A
{
void a_func();
}

class B
{
A* _a;
A* GetA(){return _a;}
}
```

And then, suppose I have an userdata object of B, b.

```
a = b:GetA();
a:a_func();
```

Question is, how can I implement B::GetA ?

Probably, you guys will let me use lightuserdata. But, as far as I can know, lightuserdata does not have individual metatable. So, even if I pushed the pointer as lightuserdata, I still can not use a_func() like above. And since I am not creating a A here, so lua_newuserdata can not be used too.

In my case, I think `lua_pushuserdata` which doesn't exist will suits me well.

---

**(UPDATE)**

```
int B::GetA_lua(lua_State* L) 
{
  void* p = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(POINTER));
  memcpy(p, &_a, sizeof(POINTER);
  lua_getmetatable();
  lua_setmetatable();
  return 1;
}

int A::a_func_lua(lua_State* L)
{
  void* p = lua_touserdata();
  (A*)(*p)->*a_func_pointer();
  return 0;
}
```

Is this a probably solution ?

Comment: You need heavy userdata not light userdata.

Comment: @francis It's lua_newuserdata(), not lua_pushuserdata

Comment: I knew lua_newuserdata(), but it's going to create the new data, which is not what I want.   Because, I have created the A instance before this function. I only need a Getter here. @Vlad

Comment: How can I use heavy userdata exactly?@lhf

Comment: @francis, creating new userdata is exactly what you need. Inside userdata you store pointer to native structure, and you can assign metatable, which will store functions to be called on that pointer. Lua-side syntax will be exactly like you want.

Comment: Did you mean **UPDATE** above?@Vlad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int B::GetA_lua(lua_State* L) 
{
  void* p = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(POINTER));
  memcpy(p, &_a, sizeof(POINTER);
  lua_getmetatable();
  lua_setmetatable();
  return 1;
}

int A::a_func_lua(lua_State* L)
{
  void* p = lua_touserdata();
  (A*)(*p)->*a_func_pointer();
  return 0;
}
```